# Checking file details before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way/function/script that we can use to check file details (extension & size) before the user actually submit the form. I'm not familiar with jquery or javascript so pls help me with that in details if that is the solution..

I'm expecting that when user select the file, using onchange command, the file will be checked and return 'tick' icon to show it is accepted and return erorr msg if the size is bigger or they use other extension.

Here is the form..

```
<table width="809" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
  <td width="252"><label for="file">Acceptance Letter from Publisher:</label></td>
  <td width="541"><input type="file" name="acceptletter" id="file" onchange="checkFile(this.value)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="252"><label for="file">Turnitin Similarity Report :</label></td>
  <td width="541"><input type="file" name="turnitin" id="file" onchange="checkFile(this.value)></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="252"><label for="file">Paper Indexing :</label></td>
  <td width="541"><input type="file" name="paperindex" id="file onchange="checkFile(this.value)"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td width="252"><label for="file">Publisher's Reviewers Report :</label></td>
  <td width="541"><input type="file" name="reviwerReport" id="file"onchange="checkFile(this.value)"></td>
  </tr></table>`
```

Comment: I've check the link you share. But it does not provide example on how I can apply it. Please help me @SamuelLiew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you have given Id **file** for all 3 elements. It should be unique.
You can get file size as follows

```
var filesize = $("#file1").files[0]·size; //gives Size in bytes.
var filename = $("#file1").files[0]·name;   //say file name "abcd.xls"

var lastIndex = filename.lastIndexOf(".");    //index of . that is 4
var extension1 = filename.substring(lastIndex);   //will give ".xls"
var extension2 = filename.substring(lastIndex+1);   //will give "xls"
```

From file name you can get the extension by substring  the last index of .

Comment: okay, i've change to file, file1, and so on. the var filename is to get the extension?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first for the 'Extension' all you have to do is take the file name/path, and do a split on the '.' char.  I.e.

```
var sFileName = document.getElementById('file').value;
var sFileExtension = sFileName.split('.')[sFileName.split('.').length - 1];
alert(sFileExtension);
```

To find the file size...

```
var iFileSize = document.getElementById('file').files[0].size;
alert(iFileSize);
```

Finally, you cannot have multiple dom elements with the same 'id' attribute.  You need to change the id="file" for all but one of them, to something different than, 'file.'  Also, it's not good coding practice to use a keyword as a unique name. Change the id of all of them to something unique and not a keyword like 'file.'

Comment: so, instead of using id='file' can i just put it like this? name="acceptletter" id="acceptletter"

Comment: nanie, you can specify which extension is accepted by using javascript as your validator. I.e, 'switch(sFileExtension){ case 'jpg': case 'png': return true; default: return false; };

Answer (score 0):

Returns the File name property:

```
fileName = fileuploadObject.name ;
```

to get the path or name:

```
fileuploadObject.value; //it's read only
```

to get file name and extension:

```
var extension = fileName.split('.').pop();
var name = fileName.split('.')[0];
```

to get File Size:

```
var fileSize = fileuploadObject.size); // in bytes
```